# How to find the smallest numbers in a json file

Tags: javascript, json

What is the best way to loop through a json object that contains integer values and select the smallest values?

For example, if I had an object that looks like this

```
var z =
{"a": 4,
 "b":2,
 "c":5,
 "d":1,
 "e":3
}
```

And I wanted to pick out the 3 smallest numbers - 1,2,3 in this case- what's the best approach?

Comment: 1. Where are you stuck? What have you tried? 2. Do you want to do this in *Java*, or *JavaScript*? They're completely different languages and environments. Your example is JavaScript. 3. Your quoted example is not JSON. If you're dealing with program source code, and you're not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Java/Javascript, in any case show your attempts

Comment: I suspect you want the answer to this in Javascript.  Could I suggest removing the Java tag, and/or state this in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Get object values into an array using **[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** loop. Then sort it using **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** and get the values

**Update :**  You can get the first 3 values using **[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**

```js
var z = {
    "a": 4,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 5,
    "d": 1,
    "e": 3
  },
  arr = [];
  // array for storing values

for (var o in z)
// iterate over the array
  arr.push(z[o]);
// push value to the array

document.write(arr
  .sort()
  // sorting the value array
  .splice(0, 3)
  // get first three values
  .join()
  // joining the 3 values              
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following script:

```
// create an array to store the values.
var numbers = [];

// loop through the keys of z and push each value in the numbers array.
for(var key in z){
    numbers.push(z[key]);
}

// sort the array. 
numbers = numbers.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b; });

// pick up the first three.
firstThree = numbers.slice(0,3);
```

```js
var z =
{"a": 4,
 "b":2,
 "c":5,
 "d":1,
 "e":3
}

var numbers = [];

for(var key in z){
    numbers.push(z[key]);
}
    
numbers = numbers.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b; });

firstThree = numbers.slice(0,3);

alert(firstThree)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to iterate over the keys of the object and use the keys for reducing the values to the smallest value.

```js
var z = {
        "a": 4,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 5,
        "d": 1,
        "e": 3
    },
    smallest = Object.keys(z).reduce(function (r, k) {
        return Math.min(r, z[k]);
    }, Number.MAX_VALUE);

document.write(smallest);
```